How do I properly buildup floor height under tile?
So I’ve begun my small tile project. I have spread thinset over the wood subfloor and set 1/4” cement board into that. Screwed it every 6”-8” into the wood beneath it with my seam taped and opposite of the joist direction. Having completed that, I now realize that 1/2” cement board would’ve been a better option because I need to make up another inch with my next thinset layer and tile. Can I apply a second layer of 1/4” cement board set into thinset on the first 1/4” cement board and screwed through all layers in the wood subfloor?  The other option is spread 5/8” of thinset on the first layer of 1/4” cement board and then set my 3/8” tiles into that to make up my 1” of height.  This seems like it’ll be a pain with that much thinset down.

It's not optimal, but another layer of 1/4 cement board is the most logical answer. How big is the room?

It’s only a 5’x4’ section set into a wood floor. I will be installing a wood stove in that area.

I would just add the extra 1/4 and call it a learning experience.
